# Multiprocessing Doesn't Create Any Extra Processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to increase the speed of my program in Python using multiprocessing, but it doesn't actually create any more processes. I've watched a few tutorials but I'm not getting anywhere.

Here it is:

```
    cpuutil = int((multiprocessing.cpu_count()) / 2)
    p = Pool(processes = cpuutil)
    output = p.map(OSGBtoETRSfunc(data, eastcol, northcol))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return output
```

So to me, this should create 2 processes on a quadcore machine, but it doesn't. My CPU util sits around 18%...

Any insight? It looks the same as the tutorials I have watched... The p.map was not working when listing arguments in square brackets ([]) so I presumed it would need to be in the syntax it is  above?

Thanks

Comment: Is your `OSGBtoETRSfunc` function returns another function or computes and return result? In the second case this would not work.

Comment: `pool.map()` should be done across iterative. For example, if you want to apply function across list `l = [1,2,3,4,5]`, you do: `pool.map(f, l)` and the result will be a list `[f(1),f(2), ...]`

Comment: @Pax0r The OSGBtoETRSfunc is a function that returns a dataframe. Why does this not work? Thanks

Comment: @Slowpoke I think .map is the wrong function then. I would like to just run a function.  Thank you.

Comment: @Fishbones78 What exactly do you want to parallelize? If you run a function once, you will have just one process running one function. You can parallelize multiple independent function calls for some list of arguments - then function will be called in parallel for all the argument values.

Comment: @Slowpoke I am trying to make a function that cycles through each row of a data frame and manipulates it. The calculation for every row is different. So I can only parallelise multiple functions, not a single function? Therefore I would need to create a function that does every nth row, then every n+1 rows for example, and then parallelise the two functions to run simultaneously?

Comment: @Fishbones78 if calculation of rows is independent (no data from calculation of n-th row is used when calculatin n+1 th), then you can do calculations for all N total rows you have in parallel. For that, you need to create a function, which calculates one given row (say, i-th). Then you split original data frame (or just prepare right ranges of indices), pass data to multiple processes, run those computations in parallel, and combine the results into new dataframe.

Comment: @Fishbones78 If you have completely different logic (and, therefore, different functions) for different rows, the former is also possible. Just each process will be running specific function.

Comment: @Slowpoke I think I will do that. Create a function that will calculate every other row, and one that calculates the others. Then append the two data frames together again. How do I get the two functions to run simultaneously? Would outputOne = p.apply(OSGBtoETRSfuncOne, [data, eastcol, northcol]) followed by outputTwo = p.apply(OSGBtoETRSfuncTwo, [data, eastcol, northcol]) work?
 Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't clearly understand what do you want, so let's start from simple. The following is a way to simply call the same function over the rows of pd dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

import pathos
from contextlib import closing

NUM_PROCESSES = os.cpu_count()
# create some data frame 100x4

nrow = 100
ncol = 4
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(nrow, ncol)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# dataframe resides in global scope
# so it is accessible to processes spawned below
# I pass only row indices to each process

# function to be run over rows
# it transforms the given row independently
def foo(idx):
    # extract given row to numpy
    row = df.iloc[[idx]].values[0]
    # you can pass ranges:
    # df[2:3]

    # transform row
    # I return it as list for simplicity of creating dataframe
    row = np.exp(row)

    # return numpy row
    return row


# run pool over range of indexes (0,1, ... , nrow-1)
# and close it afterwars
# there is not reason here to have more workers than number of CPUs
with closing(pathos.multiprocessing.Pool(processes=NUM_PROCESSES)) as pool:    
    results = pool.map(foo, range(nrow))

# create new dataframe from all those numpy slices:
col_names = df.columns.values.tolist()
df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.array(results), columns=col_names)
```

What in your computation needs more complicated setup?

EDIT: Ok, here is running two functions concurrently (I am not much familiar with pandas, so just switch to numpy):

```
# RUNNING TWO FUNCTIONS SIMLTANEOUSLY

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

# create some data frame 100x4

nrow = 100
ncol = 4
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(nrow, ncol)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# dataframe resides in global scope
# so it is accessible to processes spawned below
# I pass only row indices to each process

# function to be run over part1 independently
def proc_func1(q1):

    # get data from queue1
    data1 = q1.get()

    # I extract given data to numpy
    data_numpy = data1.values

    # do something
    data_numpy_new = data_numpy + 1

    # return numpy array to queue 1
    q1.put(data_numpy_new)

    return 


# function to be run over part2 independently
def proc_func2(q2):

    # get data from queue2
    data2 = q2.get()


    # I extract given data to numpy
    data_numpy = data2.values

    # do something
    data_numpy_new = data_numpy - 1


    # return numpy array to queue 2
    q2.put(data_numpy_new)

    return


# instantiate queues
q1 = Queue()
q2 = Queue()

# divide data frame into two parts

part1 = df[:50]
part2 = df[50:]

# send data, so it will already be in queries
q1.put(part1)
q2.put(part2)

# start two processes 
p1 = Process(target=proc_func1, args=(q1,))
p2 = Process(target=proc_func2, args=(q2,))

p1.start()
p2.start()

# wait until they finish
p1.join()
p2.join()


# read results from Queues

res1 = q1.get()
res2 = q2.get()

if (res1 is None) or (res2 is None):
    print('Error!')


# reassemble two results back to single dataframe (might be inefficient)
col_names = df.columns.values.tolist()
# concatenate results along x axis
df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([np.array(res1), np.array(res2)], axis=0), columns=col_names)
```

Comment: I understand this now, this was my confusion with the pool.map function. I was incorrectly using the map function in my first post.

I haven't explained the problem very clearly, but this has all been of help because I now understand the map function, so thank you.

With my new understanding I am left with the question, how can I run two functions simultaneously on two cores? I have split my data frame in half, so one function can calculate one half whilst the other does the second half. Then I can append them together afterwards. Continued below.

Comment: I think I can probably just research how to run two functions simultaneously rather than ask a question that I can imagine has been asked a lot of times here :).

Thank you for your help Slowpoke, now I can get something done with this project!

Comment: @Fishbones78 I've added to my answer what seems to be your use case.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you should provide the function and the arguments separated. If not, you are executing the function OSGBtoETRSfunc at the time of creating the process. Instead, you should provide the pointer to the function, and a list with the arguments.

Your case is similar to the one shown on Python Docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction

Anyway, I think you are using the wrong function. Pool.map() works as map: on a list of items and applies the same function to each item. I think that your function OSGBtoERTSfunc needs the three params in order to work properly. Please, instead of using p.map(), use p.apply()

```
cpuutil = int((multiprocessing.cpu_count()) / 2)
p = Pool(processes = cpuutil)
output = p.apply(OSGBtoETRSfunc, [data, eastcol, northcol])
p.close()
p.join()
return output
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I now see why map would not work, although this does not work for this scenario. Only one process still :)